# Windows server 2008 r2 sp1 and Sharepoint 2010: Built in web services doesn't work

Tags: wcf, windows-server

After fresh install of sharepoint server 2010 on Windows server 2008 r2 sp1 all web services doesn't work. When I try to open for example TokenService if shows me exception:

> Extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement Error:
>   Security policy export failed. The binding contains a
>   TransportSecurityBindingElement but no transport binding element that
>   implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider

After googling I found that I need to install hot fix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971493

But I can't install it. It shows: The update is not applicable to your computer. In event log: Windows update could not be installed because of error `2149842967` As I understand sp1 has newer version of this hot fix. After that I tried to implement my custom transport which implements `ITransportTokenAssertionProvider.`([MSDN Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/05/13/wcf-and-intermediate-devices.aspx))

After changing transport error has gone but a new one occurs:

> *The 'CustomBinding_'.'http://tempuri.org/' binding for the ''.'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/' contract
>   is configured with an authentication mode that requires transport
>   level integrity and confidentiality. However the transport cannot
>   provide integrity and confidentiality.*

After adding `enableUnsecuredResponse="true"` to web config new error:

> The communication object, System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[],
>   cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Seems kinda too much changes.. Maybe it would be good idea to re-run the configuration wizard and recreate the SSPs.

Comment: Already done it but without any success.

Comment: Since your're still busy with installing everything. Id' reinstall the binaries and apply SP1 on top of that before even attempting to connect the webservices. I'm talking about Sharepoint 2010 SP1 here.

Comment: sp1 doesn't help.

Comment: You have something strange in your environment. I've never had any problems with the WCF Web services on a clean install. Are you using Claims based auth? If youre using Kerberos, have you gone through the checlist? What does Sharepoint ULS say? Download ULSVIEWER (Google it) and check what it logs when you hit the web service.

Comment: It is a clean SharePoint installation. No claims authentication, we are not using kerberos. UlS viewer shows only one error:Exception returned from back end service. System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:00:09.9999999. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a possible answer here:

http://blog.libinuko.com/2013/01/19/sharepoint-2010-fixing-an-exception-was-thrown-in-a-call-to-a-policy-export-extension/

With this I can get the core web services working again, but Excel services are not working yet.